# how to create linked service to adla

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create linked service to azure data lake analytics and it is showing the error like this

```
[{"code":9512,"message":"Failed to connect to ADLA account 'miniprojectanalytics'
with error 'The client '8899dd6a-45b1-4955-a3b9-7b3a95dd6dfa' with object id
'8899dd6a-45b1-4955-a3b9-7b3a95dd6dfa' does not have authorization to perform action
'Microsoft.Authorization/permissions/read' over scope '
subscriptions/8e9519a3-7b76-40fe-9b64-752ed2d0d4dc/resourceGroups/harigrp/providers/Microsoft.DataLakeAnalytics/accounts/miniprojectanalytics/providers/Microsoft.Authorization'.
Trace: 0941cde4-bff5-42b4-8186-1bd08f04944b Time: 2018-10-05T00:27:23.0661884-07:00'."}]
```

could anyone please assist me how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to give your service account access on the ADLA via the Add User Wizard.

[From here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-data-lake-analytics)

**Service principal authentication**

The Azure Data Lake Analytics linked service requires a service principal authentication to connect to the Azure Data Lake Analytics service. To use service principal authentication, register an application entity in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) and grant it the access to both the Data Lake Analytics and the Data Lake Store it uses. For detailed steps, see Service-to-service authentication. Make note of the following values, which you use to define the linked service:

- Application ID
- Application key
- Tenant ID

Grant service principal permission to your Azure Data Lake Anatlyics using the Add User Wizard.

Comment: Have you applied the permissions on the Data Lake recursively? I advise you to double check. Here is a link with more details: https://amoghnatu.net/2017/06/13/resolving-azure-data-lake-authorization-issue/